# InvalidCultureName issue with Silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

I'm working on a silverlight application where I'm checking the url to see if the user is trying to access the "Spanish" version.  My methods work fine on Windows 7 and Windows Vista but I'm getting a crash throwing an Argument_InvalidCultureName exception when a user of Windows XP tries to load the application.  Can someone look at the code below a give me perhaps an idea of what's going wrong and how to resolve it?  Thanks in advance.

```
if (HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri.Query.Contains("Spanish") || HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri.Query.Contains("spanish") || HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri.Query.Contains("Espanol"))
{
    try
    {
           var culture = new CultureInfo("es-ES");
           Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
           Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
            // Do Something
     }
}
```

Comment: I just tried the same thing on XP and it works fine.  Where does this code live?  The MSDN doc is unhelpful "Silverlight retrieves culture information from the operating system, the availability of cultural information may vary depending on the platform and operating system version" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28VS.95%29.aspx).  What if you try another culture like "de-DE"?

Comment: What happens when you try to bring up this site on XP? https://rater.accuauto.net/?Spanish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the logic over to "es" instead of "es-ES" and this worked fine on the XP machines.